# Rails Scoping For has_many :through To Access Extra Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

As we know, in rails you can add extra attributes to your `has_many :through` join model

I'd like to extract the extra data from the join model & populate the view with it. I have got this working by referencing the join model directly, but I'd like to append the relevant join-model data to the current item, like this:

```
#app/models/message.rb
    #Images
    has_many :image_messages, :class_name => 'ImageMessage'
    has_many :images, :class_name => 'Image', :through => :image_messages, dependent: :destroy

   #app/views/messages/show.html.erb
   <%= @message.image_messages.first.caption %> #-> works

   #app/views/messages/show.html.erb
   <%= @message.images.first.caption %> #-> what I'd like to happen
```

Specifically, I need to be able to call the `caption` of a particular image, with `caption` being stored in the `image_messages` join model, like this:

```
#image_messages join table
id | message_id | image_id | caption | created_at | updated_at
```

From what I've seen, might be able to use a scope for this, but I'm not sure

Any help will be appreciated!
I figured I'd ask the question because it's one of those which you don't get that often!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution to this

The magic lies in the SQL `SELECT` statement, which I managed to find out about on [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins)

Specifically, alongside the standard `SELECT * FROM table`, you can define another function, and attach it to the original query with the [`AS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164653/whats-the-purpose-of-sql-keyword-as) function

So what I got was this code:

```
#Images
    has_many :image_messages, :class_name => 'ImageMessage'
    has_many :images, -> { select("#{Image.table_name}.*, #{ImageMessage.table_name}.caption AS caption") }, :class_name => 'Image', :through => :image_messages, dependent: :destroy
```

This allows you to attach the "caption" for the image to the `Image` object, allowing you to call `@image.caption` -- it works brilliantly!