# has_many :through uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I've read the documentations and tons of tutorials about the has_many :through relations in Rails but I can't for the life of me get the hang of it.

I'm trying to add a group to my current_user(devise) and I have a table in between `Group` and `User` with a status(The user's status is changeable for that group).

Whenever I create a new Group now I get an error saying `uninitialized constant Group::GroupUser`

here are my models:

**groupuser.rb**

```
class GroupUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to              :group
    belongs_to              :user
end
```

**group.rb**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many                            :clients
    has_and_belongs_to_many             :pictograms

    has_many :group_users
    has_many :users, :through => :group_users

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :clients

    validates_length_of                 :name,  :minimum => 5
    validates_presence_of               :name
    validates_presence_of               :background
    validates_presence_of               :clocktype
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  validates_presence_of   :first_name
  validates_presence_of   :last_name
  validates               :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  has_many :group_users
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_users

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { 
                                :medium => "300x300#", 
                                :thumb => "100x100#" 
                             }
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg']

  validates_attachment :avatar,
                  :size => { :in => 0..1.megabytes }

  def completeName
    "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
  end
end
```

And the related stuff from **schema.rb**

```
  create_table "group_users", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "status",   default: 0
  end

  add_index "group_users", ["group_id"], name: "index_group_users_on_group_id"
  add_index "group_users", ["user_id"], name: "index_group_users_on_user_id"

  create_table "groups", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "clocktype"
    t.string   "background"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "password"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
```

And lastly. **the line that throws the error**

```
@group.users << current_user
```

Comment: Maybe try calling the file `group_user.rb` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem I can see is your naming of `GroupUser`

We use join models all the time, and we also name them with an underscore:

```
group_user.rb
class GroupUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The uninitialized constant error will be caused by the model not loading correctly, which I imagine will be due to the naming issue. If that doesn't work, you should reference the model with the `:class_name` parameter in your relation declarations:

```
  has_many :group_users, :class_name => 'GroupUser'
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_users
```

---

**Update**

[We wanted to call extra attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250636/rails-scoping-for-has-many-through-to-access-extra-data) from the join model, and found this way:

```
#app/models/message.rb
has_many :image_messages, :class_name => 'ImageMessage'
has_many :images, -> { select("#{Image.table_name}.*, #{ImageMessage.table_name}.caption AS caption") }, :class_name => 'Image', :through => :image_messages, dependent: :destroy
```

This uses the `select` method which you can use when you created an ActiveRecord association, and as we [discovered from this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins), you can use that to create `alias` columns in your queries

For you, you may wish to try this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
has_many :group_users, :class_name => 'Groupuser'
has_many :groups, -> { select("#{User.table_name}.*, #{Groupuser.table_name}.status AS status") }, :class_name => 'Group', :through => :group_users, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Wow; It was that easy, huh? Thanks a lot! Works like a charm.

Comment: No problem buddy - sometimes, it's the simplest things!

Comment: I've changed the name to Groupuser for easier use :-)


Quick question though: How do I get the status from group_users to show for each user? Because when I'm looping through my Group.all and do `individualGroup.groupusers.status` nothing seems to be there. (`individualGroup.groupusers` does!)

Comment: Is status an extra attribute in your `GroupUser` join model?

Comment: Status is in my groupuser table(See schema above)

Comment: Ohh thanks! We found a way to do this - I'll post update for you

Comment: Please leave a comment when you do so I don't have to keep refreshing this page like a desperate maniac! :-p

Comment: Might not work out of the box, but we can work to fix it

Comment: Looks quite complex! I thought that was the way to go for additional attributes, I was wrong! :D I'm getting this error though: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: SELECT users.*, groupusers.status AS status FROM "groups" INNER JOIN "groupusers" ON "groups"."id" = "groupusers"."group_id" WHERE "groupusers"."user_id" = ?`

Comment: Hmm okay, do you have a `users` table, called `users`? And also, is your `groupusers` table called that? We normally call our join model tables `group_users` and similar

Comment: Schema shows: `create_table "groupusers",......` and `create_table "users",.....`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43245/discussion-between-captaincarl-and-rich-peck)

Comment: Can anyone explain why this worked?  I have a model named Box, and a model named Order, and a has_many through BoxOrder named box_order.rb and it finds the model fine?

Comment: Have you checked your database? ActiveRecord automatically creates a record in the join table and uses that as a reference.