# How to save many has_many_through objects in one form with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I'm working on an app where I have two Tables that have a many-to-many relationship, joined in the middle by a join table.

**Stadium model:**

```
class Stadium < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :stadiumteams
has_many :teams, :through => :stadiumteams
```

**Team model:**

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :stadiumteams
    has_many :stadiums, :through => :stadiumteams
end
```

**StadiumTeam model (the jointable):**

```
class StadiumTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :stadium
belongs_to :team
end
```

When I create a new Stadium I want to be able to select one or multiple teams that are associated with a stadium and save the relationship to the join-table (stadiumteams).

Here's the create action form the **Stadiums Controller**.

```
  def create
    @stadium = current_user.stadiums.build(stadium_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @stadium.save
         teams = Team.where(:id => params[:team])
         teams.each {|team| @stadium.teams << team}

        format.html { redirect_to @stadium, notice: 'Stadium was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stadium }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @stadium.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

When I try to create a new Stadium I get this output from the terminal.

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"m+HAw4LRPmozIkigzuB/SFdcAFPTL735n6FyavH0SwjGXl7NHCLmDCXMTvx8bVixz+sL7tfn1zzCl04Q+w6Pdw==", "stadium"=>{"name"=>"Friends Arena", "capacity"=>"100000", "surface"=>"", "official_opening_date(1i)"=>"2017", "official_opening_date(2i)"=>"12", "official_opening_date(3i)"=>"4", "cost"=>"10000", "web_url"=>"teststadium.com", "record_attendance"=>"999790", "city"=>"", "country"=>"", "location_name"=>"", "longitude"=>"", "latitude"=>"", "address"=>"Friends Arena, Solna, Sweden"}, "team_id"=>"3", "commit"=>"Create Stadium"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "stadiums" ("name", "capacity", "city", "country", "location_name", "address", "surface", "cost", "web_url", "record_attendance", "official_opening_date", "user_id", "latitude", "longitude", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Friends Arena"], ["capacity", 100000], ["city", "Solna"], ["country", "Sweden"], ["location_name", ""], ["address", "Friends Arena, Solna, Sweden"], ["surface", ""], ["cost", 10000.0], ["web_url", "teststadium.com"], ["record_attendance", 999790], ["official_opening_date", "2017-12-04"], ["user_id", 1], ["latitude", 59.3727005], ["longitude", 18.0002317], ["created_at", "2017-12-04 13:18:45.841931"], ["updated_at", "2017-12-04 13:18:45.841931"]]
   (2.8ms)  commit transaction
```

It seems like "team_id"=>"3"" is added as a parameter but it's not inserted into any table. And I can't output the relationship between Stadiums and Teams in any way right now.

What I want to accomplish is to be able to show all Teams that are associated with Stadium on the Stadium show page. And all Stadiums that are associated with a Team on the teams Show page.

Any help or guidance would be very appreciated!

**EDIT:**
**Stadium params:**

```
def stadium_params
  params.require(:stadium).permit(:name, :capacity, :city, :country, :location_name, :address, :longitude, :latitude, :image, :surface, :official_opening_date, :cost, :web_url, :also_known_as, :record_attendance)
end
```

**EDIT2: SOLVED:**

After struggling with this. I finally found a solution: [has_many :through uninitialized constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607327/has-many-through-uninitialized-constant)

I simply added :class_name => 'StadiumTeam' to the team and stadium model and it worked!

Comment: Can you show the view code and your stadium_params?

Comment: I don't have the code for the view fully ready yet. Just tried to access it through the rails console.

Added the stadium_params code to my main post, above!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this.

I simply added :class_name => 'StadiumTeam' to the team and stadium model and it worked!

More info here:
[has_many :through uninitialized constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607327/has-many-through-uninitialized-constant)