# Get attribute value from the join in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, join

I have a many-to-many relation between `User` and "Link".

The join model is called `LinkAddress` and besides for saving the IDs of the other two models, it has an attribute called `address` - information it collects at creation.

**How can I access the address attribute for a certain link in a request scenario like the following: `User.first.links.first.address` ?**

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :link_addresses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :links, through: :link_addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :link_addresses, allow_destroy: true
end

class LinkAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :link
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :link_addresses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :link_addresses
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access it through `User` since it's a `has_many ... :through` relation:

```
User.first.link_addresses.first.address
```

Or, if you'd like to go through `links` then:

```
User.first.links.first.link_addresses.first.address
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Aliases**

I had this exact question: [Rails Scoping For has_many :through To Access Extra Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250636/rails-scoping-for-has-many-through-to-access-extra-data)

Here's the answer I got:

```
    #Images
    has_many :image_messages, :class_name => 'ImageMessage'
    has_many :images, -> { select("#{Image.table_name}.*, #{ImageMessage.table_name}.caption AS caption") }, :class_name => 'Image', :through => :image_messages, dependent: :destroy
```

This uses [SQL Aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) which I found at [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins) (at around 6:40 in). It allows us to call `@user.image.caption` (even though `.caption` is in the join model)

---

**Your Code**

For your query, I'd use this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :link_addresses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :links, -> { select("#{Link.table_name}.*, #{LinkAddress.table_name}.address AS address") }, through: :link_addresses

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :link_addresses, allow_destroy: true
end
```

This will allow you to write `@user.links.first.address`, and gracefully handles an absence of the `address` record