# Accessing additional values on has_many through Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am having real trouble accessing the value of an additional parameter called permission on a has_many through. It is probably something simple.
My 3 Models are

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players_users
  has_many :players, through: :players_users
end
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players_users
  has_many :users, through: :players_users
end
class PlayersUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :player
  validates :player_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end
```

My controller saves the record without issue. Adding the permission value to the correct joining table.

```
def create
    @players = Player.new(players_params)
    @user= current_user
    if @players.save
      @player = Player.last
      @user.save && @user.players_users.create(:player_id =>@player.id, :permission =>"owner")
      redirect_to '/players'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

However I seem unable to access it properly
I have tried

```
perm = User.find(current_user).players_users.includes(:Permission)
 if perm == "owner"
```

Which gives an ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError, association named 'Permission' was not found on PlayersUser; perhaps you misspelled it?

I have also tried

```
 perm = User.players_users.where(player_id = @player.id && user_id = current_user)
perm.permission
```

or

```
perm = User.Player.where(player_id = @player.id && user_id = current_user)
```

or

```
perm = User.players.where(player_id = @player.id && user_id = current_user)
```

Which gives an undefined method error.
undefined method `Player'

I know this is something small in my setup but cannot figure out what it is. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `User.find(current_user).players_users.first.permission` will give you the first player_user's permission value. If you want the all, use `User.find(current_user).players_users.first.pluck(:permission)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`players_users` and `players` are associated with User object, so you can fetch the results as,

```
current_user.players_users.pluck(:permission)
```

Comment: had to change slightly @permission = current_user.players_users.where(player_id: params[:player_id], user_id: current_user).pluck(:permission)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250636/rails-scoping-for-has-many-through-to-access-extra-data) before with my own code.

---

I'll post that in a second, but first you need to refactor your controller, the current is inefficient:

```
#app/controllers/players_controller.rb
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
    def create
       @player = current_user.players.new players_params
       if @player.save
          current_user.player_users.find(@player.id).update(permission: "owner")
          redirect_to players_path
       end
    end

    private

    def player_params
       params.require(:player).permit(....)
    end
end
```

To access the `permission` of the `player_user`, you'll need to use the following:

```
@permission = current_user.player_users.find(@player.id).permission
```

--

A much more [`DRY`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) approach (if you're explicitly setting `permission` as `owner` each time) would be to introduce an [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) into the `Player` model to act as a default:

```
#app/models/player.rb
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum permission: [:owner, :member, :moderator] #-> defaults to :owner
end
```

This will do away with having to define the `permission` in the `create` method (unless of course you *want* to change it):

```
#app/controllers/players_controller.rb
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
    def create
       @player = current_user.players.new players_params
       redirect_to players_path if @player.save
    end
end
```

To understand this, you must remember that since `player_users` is a *join* association, `ActiveRecord` will automatically populate it if you create a player on the `current_user` object (`current_user.players`).

---

[**Association Extensions**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions)

In regard to pulling the `permission` data, I built a script which appends the permission to the `player` object (uses `proxy_association.target` etc):

```
#current
@player     = current_user.players.find params[:player_id]
@permission = current_user.player_users.find(params[:player_id]).permission

#script
@player     = current_user.players.find params[:player_id]
@permission = @player.permission
```

It works similarly to an [`SQL Alias column`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) - so whilst you cannot manipulate the data, it will allow you to call `@user.players.find(params[:player_id].permission`.. except it's all done *in memory*:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :player_users
   has_many :players, through: :player_users, -> { extending PlayerPermission }
end

#app/models/concerns/player_permission.rb
module PlayerPermission

        #Load
        def load
          permissions.each do |permission|
              proxy_association.target << permission
          end
        end

        #Private
        private

        #Permissions
        def permissions
           return_array = []
           through_collection.each_with_index do |through,i|
              associate = through.send(reflection_name)
              associate.assign_attributes({permission: items[i]})
              return_array.concat Array.new(1).fill( associate )
           end
           return_array
        end

        #######################
        #      Variables      #
        #######################

        #Association
        def reflection_name
           proxy_association.source_reflection.name
        end

        #Foreign Key
        def through_source_key
           proxy_association.reflection.source_reflection.foreign_key
        end

        #Primary Key
        def through_primary_key
           proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.active_record_primary_key
        end

        #Through Name
        def through_name
           proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection.name
        end

        #Through
        def through_collection
           proxy_association.owner.send through_name
        end

        #Captions
        def items
            through_collection.map(&:permission)
        end

        #Target
        def target_collection
            #load_target
            proxy_association.target
        end

end
```

--

As an aside, [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) is to keep all aspects of a `model` name `singular` (`ProductUser`).

Comment: If you have a problem, respond and we'll get it working

Comment: Hi @RichPeck, thanks for such a detailed answer however it has continued to throw the same permission errors for me.

Comment: Hi @richpeck, it all worked had to really start from scratch and followed convention, must have been making a mistake switching from plural and back.

Comment: Yep - as a rule the model should always be `Singular` (in all instances -- `ProductUser`)

Comment: BTW do you want me to help you implement the "proxy association" method? It's all in-memory